# What causes these 'not defined by the user' errors?

Tags: java, html, xml, soapui

Why I get these errors?

```
<! [CDATA [An error occurred on the server: not defined by the user]]>
    #status# HTTP / 1.1 500 internal server Error


<! [ CDATA [ An error occurred on the server: not defined by the user]]> 
    #status#  HTTP / 1.1 500 internal server Error
```

Comment: That message isn't really enough to determine the cause. Can you share your java code? It is a likely cause of the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your server wants a json object, but you've sent an xml/html object, so it can't be parsed as a json. Xml/html starts with "<" symbol

Comment: yes, the server wants a json object, but you've sent an xml/html object.